# Is there a better way to get a child?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have written the following code to get `ImageColorPicker` child:

```
foreach (CustomTabItem customTabItem in SelectedWindowsTabControl.Items)
{
    TabItem ti = tabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(customTabItem) as TabItem;
    Popup popup = (Helpers.FindVisualChild<Popup>(ti) as Popup);
    ImageColorPicker icp = (popup.Child as StackPanel).Children[0] as ImageColorPicker;

    ...
}

public class Helpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Return the first visual child of element by type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the Child</typeparam>
    /// <param name="obj">The parent Element</param>
    public static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
                return (T)child;
            else
            {
                T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's the control template XAML of the `TabItem` (the relevant part):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomTabItem}">
    <Grid Height="26" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ContentPresenter Margin="5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header">
        </ContentPresenter>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Height="16" Margin="0,0,1,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ToggleButton x:Name="Edit" Width="16" Content="&#xE104;" Style="{StaticResource CustomizedMetroTabItemToggleButton}" ToolTip="Edit" />
            <Popup HorizontalOffset="{Binding Width, ElementName=Edit}" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=Edit}" Placement="Left" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Edit}" PopupAnimation="Slide" StaysOpen="False" VerticalOffset="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Edit}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <local:ImageColorPicker x:Name="ColorPicker" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/ColorWheel.png" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Popup>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Is there a better way to get the `ImageColorPicker` than what I've done? (getting the `TabItem`, then the `Popup` and then the `ImageColorPicker`, I am sure there's a shorter way)

Comment: You should try to find a woman that also wants a child this will increase chances. Now seriously: Try to find more descriptive (and less ambiguous) titles :)

Comment: nah, title is ok - funny titles draw attention ;) (`pill.Forget();` would be a good way!)

Comment: We do have a [parenting site on StackExchange](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/) for those interested.

Comment: Hot Network Questions pitcher plant title of the week!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't like a class that's just called `Helpers` - that's generally a code smell, something that ends up a big dumping ground for anything that doesn't quite fit anywhere else. Be more specific when naming things, perhaps `VisualHierarchyHelper` would be a better name?

I'm using a very similar method - the main difference is essentially the number ot `return` statements, and the `childName` parameter; I found this code on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759923/1188513) a little while ago:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds a Child of a given item in the visual tree. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parent">A direct parent of the queried item.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the queried item.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="childName">x:Name or Name of child. </param>
    /// <returns>The first parent item that matches the submitted type parameter. 
    /// If not matching item can be found, 
    /// a null parent is being returned.</returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759923/1188513
    /// </remarks>
    public static T FindChild<T>(this DependencyObject parent, string childName)
       where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (parent == null) return null;

        T foundChild = null;

        var childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (var i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            var childType = child as T;
            if (childType == null)
            {
                foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);
                if (foundChild != null) break;
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
            {
                var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                {
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foundChild = (T)child;
                break;
            }
        }

        return foundChild;
    }
```

Notice the *guard clause* preventing a `NullReferenceException` that your method would throw if `obj` was `null`. I think this is a pretty neat way of finding a child node in the visual tree.

That said, it might be personal preference, but I think the readability of your code could benefit from implicit typing (`var`), especially in cases like this where the type is already pretty obvious:

```
TabItem ti = tabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(customTabItem) as TabItem;
Popup popup = (Helpers.FindVisualChild<Popup>(ti) as Popup);
ImageColorPicker icp = (popup.Child as StackPanel).Children[0] as ImageColorPicker;
```

Becomes:

```
var ti = tabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(customTabItem) as TabItem;
var popup = (Helpers.FindVisualChild<Popup>(ti) as Popup);
var icp = (popup.Child as StackPanel).Children[0] as ImageColorPicker;
```

And here you would have to make sure `popup` isn't `null` before accessing its `Child` member, if you want to avoid that possible `NullReferenceException`.

Also, you're casting too much - `T` should be of the type you've specified, so the return type of `FindChild<ImageColorPicker>` is `ImageColorPicker`, casting it to `ImageColorPicker` is redundant.

---

#### Update

The `ImageColorPicker` child has a `Popup` parent, which has a `StackPanel` parent, which has a `Grid` parent, which has a `TabItem` parent.

You're not fully using the recursiveness of your function when you're getting the color picker. I'd believe you could get it like this:

```
var tab = tabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(customTabItem) as TabItem;
var picker = VisualHierarchyHelper.FindChild<ImageColorPicker>(tab, "ColorPicker");
```

That should work, because the search is recursive; you don't need to get everything in-between.

Comment: Thats not exactly what I meant. Right now I use  3 lines to get the ImageColorPicker (btw, the Popup will never be null).
Why cant I just do something like `TabItem ti = tabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(customTabItem) as TabItem; ImageColorPicker icp = Helpers.FindVisualChild<ImageColorPicker(ti) as ImageColorPicker;`

Comment: There's one `ImageColorPicker` control in the `TabItem` but still, the picker variable is null, why is that?

Comment: Even with this `FindVisualChild<T>` implementation? (I'm investigating it right now)

Comment: Yes, even with the `FindVisualChild<T>` implementation. Something is weird and I cant understand what

Comment: @Ron that's weird, I'm using it to find a named `ComboBox` in a templated `ListViewItem` (has `Border` and `Grid` parents), no issues, but the ComboBox has a `x:Name`. Have you tried giving an `x:Name` to the color picker element? Other than that, I'm afraid *telling you why the code doesn't work as expected* is beyond the scope of this site (Stack Overflow can certainly help there).

Comment: Yes, the ColorPicker has `x:Name`                                                 `<local:ImageColorPicker x:Name="ColorPicker" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/ColorWheel.png" />` The control is based on Image control, maybe thats the issue.. I will investigate it my self

Comment: Maybe there's something to do with that `Popup` is `System.Controls.Primitives`

Comment: `Image` and `Popup` are both `FrameworkElement` derivatives, it shouldn't matter. Wow you just got me scratching my head now!

Comment: From MSDN: When you add content to a Popup control, the Popup control becomes the logical parent to the content. Similarly, the Popup content is considered to be the logical child of the Popup. The child content is not added to the visual tree that contains the Popup control. Instead, the child content is rendered in a separate window that has its own visual tree when the IsOpen property is set to true.

Comment: i was looking around on SO and google for far too long. this did the trick tough, thx!